# Display Board that turns

Tags: power-supply, motor

I’m building a flag-shaped display box for patches.  I will need 3-4 dozen motors I assume running parallel that will turn 180 degrees every set amount of minutes (maybe 3 or 5).  The motor will be turning silicone envelopes containing 2 approx 3”x5” patches hanging from the motor.  I’ve never done anything like this lol. But I’m spending the next month learning, planning and experimenting before attempting to assemble anything.  I’d like to learn some skills.  A friend who is an engineer will be lending some in person assistance.  But in the vast universe of small motors, I was hoping for some suggestions of which to look at first and suggestions for a power supply.  Will a separate device be needed to control the timing of the motors.  If a timer is introduced at the power source, will running the motors parallel mean they begin flipping in relay?  I’m not opposed to that.  Would each motor need a timing device to have them flip at the same time?  I understand with zero understanding at this point that I’m asking for a lot, but just a few starting points to begin my research will help immensely.  I’m drowning in too much info without items to focus on first.

Comment: A clock's seconds hand turns 180 degrees every 30 seconds. But the term "flip" is used in connection with turning after a delay. These two scenarios might use totally different actuation mechanisms. You might specify how fast a "flip" of 180 degrees is required, and how much mass is to be moved.

Comment: Are you expecting to rotate all of these cards at the same time and in sync? Or do you want full control over each and every motor?  Using separate servo motors is a potential option. There are several Arduino projects for controlling large numbers of separate servo motors. Should be easy to find, including pre=written software.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at servos for this. They take a pulse width modulated (PWM) signal and rotate an output shaft to a specific repeatable position based on the duty cycle (ratio of on time to off time) of the input. Servos with 180- or 270-degree rotation are very common, continuous rotation 360-degree servos are slightly less so but still easy to get your hands on. There are myriad guides and Arduino libraries etc for controlling them so it should be a snap to set up, very appropriate for a first time project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use something like hobby motors it’s going to require a means of limiting the rotation. A sensor would detect when they have rotated the correct amount and shut off the motor. This would probably need a microcontroller.

Stepper motors would give you more control over the rotation. You would need some type of microcontroller such as Arduino to control them.

If you want all of the patches to flip simultaneously you should probably look at a mechanical method where they are connected by gears, belts or levers. That way you would only need a single motor or maybe a solenoid or linear actuator. Mechanical parts could be done with 3D printing. Again, a micro would probably be needed.

It could also be done mechanically with a timer motor, the motor is geared to turn slowly and uses a cam to control the motion.